# Multiple conditional using AppleScript in Indesign -- won't work?

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

This is making me lose my mind. Here's a short version of thee code that I'm trying to get to work. It's returning bizarre values and giving me errors at random height and width settings. I can't for the life of me figure out where I went wrong! I thought my logic gate to determine the inputs was rock solid! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS6"
    activate
    set myDoc to active document

    set origLevel to user interaction level of script preferences
    set user interaction level of script preferences to interact with all

    set myDialog to make dialog with properties {name:"Make Template", can cancel:true}
    tell myDialog
        tell (make dialog column)
            tell (make border panel)
                tell (make dialog column)
                    make static text with properties {static label:"Width:", min width:60}
                    make static text with properties {static label:"Height:", min width:60}
                    make static text with properties {static label:"Bleed:", min width:60}
                end tell
                tell (make dialog column)
                    set myWidth to make text editboxes with properties {edit contents:"", min width:60}
                    set myHeight to make text editboxes with properties {edit contents:"", min width:60}
                    set myBleed to make text editboxes with properties {edit contents:"", min width:60}
                end tell
                tell (make dialog column)
                    make static text with properties {static label:"in", min width:0}
                    make static text with properties {static label:"in", min width:0}
                    make static text with properties {static label:"in", min width:0}
                end tell
                tell (make dialog column)
                    make static text with properties {static label:"", min width:25}
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell

    set userResponse to show myDialog
    if userResponse is true then
        set docWidth to edit contents of myWidth as string
        set docHeight to edit contents of myHeight as string
        set docBleed to edit contents of myBleed as string
        destroy myDialog
    else
        destroy myDialog
        error number -128
    end if

    tell myDoc

        if docHeight > docWidth then
            set bigDim to docHeight
        else
            set bigDim to docWidth
        end if

        if bigDim ≤ 216 then
            set buildSize to "1"
        else if bigDim > 216 and bigDim ≤ 432 then
            set buildSize to "2"
        else if bigDim > 432 and bigDim ≤ 864 then
            set buildSize to "4"
        else if bigDim > 864 and bigDim ≤ 2160 then
            set buildSize to "10"
        end if

        set newWidth to (docWidth / buildSize)
        set newHeight to (docHeight / buildSize)
        set newBleed to (docBleed / buildSize)

        set document bleed top offset of document preferences to newBleed
        set page width of document preferences to newWidth
        set page height of document preferences to newHeight

    end tell

    set user interaction level of script preferences to origLevel
end tell
```

Comment: Descriptions of expected results and actual error messages would be helpful.

Comment: When I set the height and width to "5", it returns with a scale size of 25%. Even if I remove all the other if-then statements and just say "if bigDim ≤ 216 then set buildSize to "1", it doesn't work. It just says that buildSize is not defined -- which would only happen if my input was > 216. It just makes no sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write

```
    set docWidth to edit contents of myWidth as string
    set docHeight to edit contents of myHeight as string
```

and in fact you compare a string with an integer: `if bigDim ≤ 216 then`. To handle your code Applescript has to convert one of these values and it looks like it converts the value 216 to a string "216". Using string comparison the string "5" is greater than "216" and fits the comparison `else if bigDim > 432 and bigDim ≤ 864 then`, because the string "5" fits between "432" and "864".

What about converting the edit contents to integer?

```
    set docWidth to edit contents of myWidth as integer
    set docHeight to edit contents of myHeight as integer
```

BTW the used code `set newWidth to (docWidth / buildSize)` later in your script worked only because Applescript is clever enough to convert both values to numbers because it just don't make sense to divide two strings ;-)

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg